# Upload json File to Specific Folder in s3 Bucket in Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I have python code that uploads a json file into an s3 bucket in AWS. Below is the code that works:

```py
ACCESS_KEY = '##########'
SECRET_KEY = '######################/####'


def upload_to_aws(schoolID, bucketName):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

    try:
        s3.upload_file(schoolID, bucketName, schoolID)
        print(schoolID + " Upload Successful")
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(schoolID + " The file was not found")
        return False
    except NoCredentialsError:
        print(schoolID + " Credentials not available")
        return False


uploaded = upload_to_aws(schoolID + '.json', 'bucketName')
```

However, I now want to upload it to a specific folder in the s3 bucket. I tried editing the following line in the above code:

```py
uploaded = upload_to_aws(schoolID + '.json', 'bucketName\AcademicYears')
```

But I got this error:

```
ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "bucketName\AcademicYears": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:s3:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$"
```

Does anyone know how I can alter this code to make it work? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're adding a string to your bucket which AWS is rejecting. Subdirs are added to the bucket key.

If your bucket is named "bucketName" then this is the top directory. Anything under this directory will be added to the key.

For example:

- bucketName <-- bucket

  - AcademicYears <-- subdir

    - school_id_file.json <--file

Try:

```
uploaded = upload_to_aws('AcademicYears/' + schoolID + '.json', 'bucketName')
```

Comment: Thanks, my bucket is just called BucketName. My folder inside the bucket is called 'AcademicYears'

Comment: Okay. I'll edit. This is probably going to give you a file not found error unless your local directory is setup exactly like your aws directories.

Comment: Thanks so much @OllieinPGH. This is my code to create the json file and save it:         AcademicYears.to_json(schoolID + '.json', default_handler=str, orient='records', lines=True). How could I make this save in an AcademicYears folder so it won't through an error?

Comment: Is that a pandas Dataframe? Try: `AcademicYears.to_json('AcademicYears' + schoolID + '.json', default_handler=str, orient='records', lines=True)` You just have to make the folder `AcademicYears` on your local computer (laptop, desktop, whatever.)